# declaring an array of objects with different parameters

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization, default

C# programming class
    typeObject[] array = new typeObject[5];
Furthermore, the typeObject has a constructor that takes in an integer.
How do you call each object with different integers than relying on default constructor?
Thank you.

Comment: I meant to declare each index of the array to a different passed parameter for the constructor. Essentially what I want is array[1] = new typeObject(3);
array[2] = new typeObject(15); ...

Answer (score 3):

You may either construct the elements in the array directly:

```
typeObject[] array = new typeObject[5];
array[0] = new typeObject(1);
array[1] = new typeObject(2);
```

or you may use array initializers:

```
typeObject[] array = new typeObject[]{new typeObject(1), new typeObject(2), ... new typeObject(5)};
```

Comment: for the first option, wouldn't the first statement declare all the objects with the default constructor though? Thank you @William

Comment: @LeonardLie In the first code example, each element of the array would be initialized to the default value of `typeObject`. If that's a class, then each element would be null. If that's a struct, e.g. a `DateTime`, then it would be roughly equivalent to calling the parameterless constructor for the struct--although you can't actually define a custom parameterless constructor for a struct, the compiler provides it for you.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using the code you cited in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19310672/declaring-an-array-of-objects-with-different-parameters/19310751#comment28600448_19310672):

```
typeObject[] array = new typeObject[5];
array[0] = new typeObject(7); // note: array indexes start at 0
array[1] = new typeObject(3);
array[2] = new typeObject(15);
...
```

But if you'd like to do it one statement, you can always use the array initializer syntax:

```
typeObject[] array = new typeObject[] 
{
    new typeObject(7),
    new typeObject(3),
    new typeObject(15),
};
```

Comment: Thank you. So, the first statement in your second code would not call the default constructor of the typeObject class? @p.s.w.g

Comment: @LeonardLie The second code block only contains a single statement, which constructs *N* objects using the specified constructor (not a parameterless one) and initializes a new array which contains those objects as elements.

Comment: No, it just creates the array. The elements of the array are empty until initialise with the new typeObject() statements.